# Where is kernel_task?

Tags: macos, big-sur, kernel

I see `kernel_task` in Activity monitor. But I cannot find where the binary file is using Spotlight. Does anybody know where the binary is found on the disk? I am using Big Sur 11.4. But my question may not be related to the particular version of the OS.

Comment: Why do you need to know where the binary is. You can't do anything with it

Answer (score 5):

The process name `kernel_task` is artificially set by the `xnu` kernel itself during initialization (see **[`bsd_init()`](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/bsd/kern/bsd_init.c#L483)**) as a way to represent the kernel's threads to users and other processes within the BSD layer as part of its process accounting system. The kernel binary lives in `/System/Library/Kernels/kernel`. However, recent releases of macOS do not load this image directly. For both speed and security reasons, that binary gets prelinked along with all of its active kernel extensions (KEXTs) and the prelinked image is stored in `/System/Library/PrelinkedKernels` on Intel Macs or the `Preboot` volume on Apple Silicon Macs. *That* is the actual image that is loaded upon boot firmware control handoff.