# How to turn off kernel_task on Big Sur?

Tags: big-sur, kernel-extensions

I would like to turn off kernel_task.

[Where is kernel_task?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431965/where-is-kernel-task?noredirect=1#comment619172_431965)

As discussed here, it is prelinked with KEXTs. So by changing KEXTs, it can be turned off?

Could anybody show me how to turn off kernel_task on Big Sur?

Comment: Why do you want to turn it off? It will stop macos running

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to turn off `kernel_task` - except by turning off your computer.

`kernel_task` is not a normal process (running program), but rather a representation of some of the functionality that is implemented by the operating system kernel. Amongst functionality implemented by the kernel is for example: accessing disk drives (also SSDs), communicating on networks (Ethernet, WiFi, etc.), talking to peripherals (such as making keyboards, trackpads work and getting things to show up on the display). If you could disable `kernel_task`, it would cause all programs that require the operating system (that is effectively all programs on your computer) to stop working.

Comment: Are you sure your answer is correct? I see something here. https://grafxflow.co.uk/blog/mac-os-x/delete-ioplatformpluginfamilykext-macos-big-sur So it should be doable. The only thing is that this post assumes something that my system does not satisfy. So I am looking for a solution that does not need this requirement.

Comment: Yes, I’m 100% sure the answer is correct. The link you have concerns disabling a specific feature in macOS where when it senses the system temperature becomes too high, it tries to lower the temperature by forcing the CPU to idle. It hasn’t got anything to do with “turning off” kernel_task as such. Perhaps you should ask a question with your actual problem you’re trying to solve - I assume you have a too hot system or you’re looking at something and think kernel_task is using the CPU (where in fact it is actually precisely the opposite it is doing - making sure no one uses the CPU).

Comment: Done. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432046/how-to-not-let-kernel-task-take-too-much-cpu-when-the-machine-is-hot

Answer (score 0):

Dust might be obstructing some of the fans and the airflow inside the case.  You could try removing the case cover and gently use some canned air duster to make sure connections are not damaged while cleaning.